# Smaller chunk size or disabling Zeroing?

Tags: windows-7, lvm, thin

On a CentOS 7 server with 4X Samsung 800 SD with hard raid 10 I am using KVM for virtualization. I created a thin LVM storage for VMs and using "lvcreate -l 100%FREE --type thin-pool --thinpool thin_pool vgssd" gave me the following:

Thin pool volume with chunk size 1.00 MiB can address at most 253.00 TiB of data
  **WARNING: Pool zeroing and 1.00 MiB large chunk size slows down thin provisioning**
  WARNING: Consider disabling zeroing (-Zn) or using smaller chunk size (<512.00 KiB).
  Logical volume "thin_pool" created.

What do you think about the chunk size? Is Zeroing necessary? VM performance is important to me, they are mostly Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend using smaller chunk sizes and **do not disable Zeroing!**

My fuckup story:
Proxmox Server with an LVM storage setup as
`lvcreate -l 100%FREE --thinpool myVolumeGroup/myLogicalVolume -Zn`
All my VMs had an OS disk and a separate data disk. Regular backups were running via Proxmox Backup. The restore of the backups seemed fine upon first look, but the data disk was corrupted:
`Error: Both the primary and backup GPT tables are corrupt.  Try making a fresh table, and using Parted's rescue feature to recover partitions.`
Backups were worthless. Time is ticking.
In a [proxmox forum thread](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/corrupt-gpt-after-restore-on-pve-7-0-from-backup-on-pve-6-4-qemu-vm-lvm-thin-storage-ovmf.94785/) someone had the same issue:
`The troublemaker has been found: Due to a hint when creating the thinpool, I added flag -Zn so that the first 4k of volumes on their creation are not set to zero.`

**Solution if you already disabled Zeroing on a production server:**
`lvchange -Z y myVolumeGroup/myLogicalVolume`